# Is there a elegant way to name the elements of a list according to the variables it has been composed of?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a function that does the same as `list`, but puts the names of the input variables into the element names of the list:

```
a <- 2
b <- c("foo","bar")
betterlist(a,b)

[[a]]
[1] 2

[[b]]
[1] "foo" "bar"
```

In the output of `list(a,b)`, the names `"a"` and `"b"` would not appear. Does it already exist in any package?

Comment: I don't know if this any better, but you could do `mget(ls(pattern = "[a-z]"))` or if you don't have any other objects in your environment, could do just `mget(ls())`

Comment: Or `mget(c("a", "b"))`.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I agree, it's a duplicate. I might have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using ... :

```
betterlist = function(...) {
  result <- list(...)
  resultnames <- lapply(substitute(list(...)), deparse)
  names(result) <- resultnames[-1]
  return(result)
}
```

This should actually be even easier as the [R help](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-three-dots-argument) states

> The expression list(...) evaluates all such arguments and returns them in a named list [...]

but for me, list(...) gives me an unnamed list (hence the explicit naming in the function above).

Answer (score 0):

First guess:

```
list(a = a, b = b)
```